# Joomla - Custom module not showing

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla3.0

I have an issue where I try to load custom modules into my index.php page and they are not showing up at all, when I give my menu module the position of the custom one the menu shows up. 
(Using Joomla: 3.6.5)

Im using this code in my index.php to load the module

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="blokmodule" />
```

I made a position in templateDetails so that not where the problem is.

Comment: do you have any code to show your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have through this tutorial https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module before creating your custom module. Now once you have created a module you need to display it in the frontpage. To do that

1. your module should output some data
2. your module should be published
3. Should be assigned a template position
4. In the menu assignment it should have either all or some menu selected. Else it wont display if Module Assignment is "no pages".
5. Check if the permissions are set correct so that a user can view it.